# From a TypeScript VS Code extension, is it possible to change the color of a specific range of text in the editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

From a TypeScript VS Code extension, is it possible to change the color of a specific range of text in the editor?

Comment: look for `Decorator` on the API page